# WPF Devexpress Documentgroup with different documents

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, mvvm, devexpress

I am trying to accomplish this scenario with MVVM.
I want to have a DockLayoutManager with some dynamic documents and each document will show different view.

So let's say that I have the the DockLayoutManager  with its ViewModel and I have 3 other views (usercontrols) with their own viewmodels
My code for the MainWIndow.xaml:

```
  <UserControl x:Class="BrowserTabManager"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars"
         xmlns:dxd="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/docking"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFiRecsTest1"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         d:DesignHeight="600"
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         mc:Ignorable="d">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:BrowserTabManagerViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ResultsViewModel}">
        <local:ResultsView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:WorksheetViewModel}">
        <local:WorksheetView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CrystalReportViewModel}">
        <local:CrystalReportView />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<dxd:DockLayoutManager FloatingMode="Desktop">
    <dxd:LayoutGroup>
        <dxd:LayoutGroup x:Name="panelHost" />
        <dxd:DocumentGroup x:Name="documentHost" ItemsSource="{Binding TabPages}" />
    </dxd:LayoutGroup>
</dxd:DockLayoutManager>
</UserControl>
```

The good thing is that is working. Each document has its own view. But I cannot figure how and where I should bind the header caption:

The code for BrowserTabManagerViewModel:

```
 Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
 Imports DevExpress.Mvvm
 Public Class BrowserTabManagerViewModel
 Inherits ViewModelBase

Private mTabPages As New ObservableCollection(Of ViewModelBase)()
Public Property TabPages() As ObservableCollection(Of ViewModelBase)
    Get
        Return mTabPages
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of ViewModelBase))
        RaisePropertyChanged("TabPages")
    End Set
End Property

Private miSelectedTabIndex As Integer
Public Property SelectedTabIndex() As Integer
    Get
        Return miSelectedTabIndex
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        If value <> miSelectedTabIndex Then
            miSelectedTabIndex = value
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTabIndex")
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()
    mTabPages.Add(New ResultsViewModel()) 
    mTabPages.Add(New WorksheetViewModel()) 
    mTabPages.Add(New CrystalReportViewModel())
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I cannot figure how and where I should bind the header caption

You should declare that binding via the DocumentPanel's default style:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="dxd:DocumentPanel"> 
        <Setter Property="Caption" Value="{Binding ViewModelPropertyForCaption}" /> 
    </Style> 
    ...
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ResultsViewModel}">
    ...

</UserControl.Resources>
```

The best solution for the situation, described in the original question, is creating the base type for all of these ViewModels and separating the Header property into this class:

```
public class BaseDocumentViewModel {
    public virtual string ViewModelPropertyForCaption { get; set; }
}
...
public class ResultsViewModel : BaseDocumentViewModel {
    //...
}
```

Related help-article: [MVVM Support - Building Dock UI](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument11386).

A complete example is available online at: [How to Build a dock UI using the MVVM pattern](http://www.devexpress.com/example=E3911).

Comment: I know the mentioned examples. The problem is that their solution is for one type of panel and one type of document. 
I have many different types of Documents, each with its own viewmodel

Comment: The best solution for this situation is creating the base type for all of these viewmodels and separating the Header property into this class. Is this possible with your class structure?

Comment: I just accomplished it. I'll post my solution

Comment: @Nianios hmm...it is not good to embed UI controls (UserControls) into ViewModels. Moreover, your solution introduced an additional level of ViewModels (BrowserTabViewModel -> Content-> Specific ViewModel For Content). You can avoid this by using inheritance. Anyway, your approach will work as expected...

p.s. I believe it is posible to replace`<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">...` with `<Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Content}" />`

Comment: Thanks Dmitry.  I'll check the inheritance to avoid the additional Level of ViewModels. Your suggestion for the Content works. Could you please provide a solution without a reference to the usercontrols?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way to do it, (maybe not the best one)

So the xaml is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BrowserTabManager"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars"
         xmlns:dxd="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/docking"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFiRecsTest1"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         d:DesignHeight="600"
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         mc:Ignorable="d">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:BrowserTabManagerViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<UserControl.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type dxd:DocumentPanel}">
           <Setter Property="Caption" Value="{Binding DisplayName}" />
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<dxd:DockLayoutManager x:Name="dockLayoutManager"
                       ClosedPanelsBarVisibility="Never"
                       ClosingBehavior="ImmediatelyRemove"
                       FloatingMode="Desktop"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding TabPages}">

    <dxd:LayoutGroup x:Name="panelHost">
        <dxd:DocumentGroup x:Name="documentHost" />
    </dxd:LayoutGroup>
</dxd:DockLayoutManager>
</UserControl>
```

I have a viewmodel for the documents (BrowserTabViewModel) which has a property for the Caption (displayName) and one for the Content of the Document(TabPage is the Model):

```
Public Property Content() As UserControl
    Get
        Return TabPage.Content
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As UserControl)
        TabPage.Content = value
        RaisePropertyChanged("Content")
    End Set
End Property
```

Now the main ViewModel (BrowserTabManagerViewModel) is like this:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports DevExpress.Mvvm
Public Class BrowserTabManagerViewModel
Inherits ViewModelBase



Private mTabPages As New ObservableCollection(Of BrowserTabViewModel)()
Public Property TabPages() As ObservableCollection(Of BrowserTabViewModel)
    Get
        Return mTabPages
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of BrowserTabViewModel))
        RaisePropertyChanged("TabPages")
    End Set
End Property



Public Sub New()

    mTabPages.Add(New BrowserTabViewModel() With {.Type = "RES", .DisplayName = "Result1", .Content = New ResultsView})

    mTabPages.Add(New BrowserTabViewModel() With {.Type = "WOR", .DisplayName = "worksheet", .Content = New WorksheetView})

    mTabPages.Add(New BrowserTabViewModel() With {.Type = "CRR", .DisplayName = "Crystal", .Content = New CrystalReportView})

    mTabPages.Add(New BrowserTabViewModel() With {.Type = "DXR", .DisplayName = "DX REport", .Content = New DXReportView})

    mTabPages.Add(New BrowserTabViewModel() With {.Type = "DAR", .DisplayName = "Data Report", .Content = New DataReportView})

    mTabPages.Add(New BrowserTabViewModel() With {.Type = "ADD", .DisplayName = "+", .Content = New BrowserAddMenuView})
End Sub
End Class
```

If anyone has any suggestions for improvement please let me know.